# error query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from user WHERE gender='$gender' DESC limit 15

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me

Error message:

```
error query: "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
               FROM user WHERE gender='$gender'
               DESC limit 15";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies somewhere in this line:

```
...WHERE gender='$gender' DESC limit 15
```

As you can see, you have no `ORDER BY` clause but you have used `DESC` keyword. Try fixing it by removing the keyword `DESC`

```
...WHERE gender='$gender' limit 15
```

or adding `ORDER BY` clause

```
...WHERE gender='$gender' ORDER BY col_name DESC limit 15
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle either of the two options should work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `user` WHERE `gender`='$gender' LIMIT 15;
```

or run the query without `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and do a  separate `SELECT COUNT(*)` query

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `gender`='$gender' LIMIT 10;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE `gender`='$gender';
```

PS: It is a good habit to backtick the field-names.